# How to set font sizes in minimal X Window setup

Tags: x11, fonts, settings

I installed openSUSE with generic/minimal desktop environment. It means there is no fancy KDE/Gnome settings program for setting the font sizes by default.

On the other system I did the same, but installed additionally KDE3 (not a typo, 3).

In both system I have the same visual effect -- for applications like LibreOffice, VLC, Firefox the font used by the program in menus and dialogs is tiny. So how can I set the font size for such apps?

**Update**:

```
xset q | grep -e "Font Path:" -A2
```

gives

```
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/misc:unscaled,/usr/share/fonts/Type1/,
  /usr/share/fonts/100dpi:unscaled,/usr/share/fonts/75dpi:unscaled,
  /usr/share/fonts/ghostscript/,/usr/share/fonts/cyrillic:unscaled,
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/,built-ins,/home/myself/.fonts
DPMS (Energy Star):
```

```
xdpyinfo | grep -B2 resolution
```

produces:

```
screen #0:
  dimensions:    1920x1200 pixels (508x317 millimeters)  
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

Resolution is correct, however size in mm is slightly off (it should be something like 485 x 295 mm).

Comment: Can you check that the 96x96 dpi corresponds to the output of `xrdb -query | grep dpi` ? Do you use an unusual driver for your display ? Do you have font configuration files in `/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail`?  (Just trying to root out obvious things here, not just randomly asking you stuff).

Comment: @Cbhihe Thank you again, I updated the question/output. `xrdb` itself produces ton of output but there is no such entry as "dpi" so grep filters out everything. "conf.avail" file exists but it contains only single comment I believe `*** /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail: directory ***`.